# No carga el calendario de DatePicker

Tags: bootstrap, angular, angular6

La pregunta es muy simple. Tengo todo incluido correctamente, pero el selector de fecha simplemente no aparece en mi formulario. Este es código del selector de la fecha

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>
```

Y eso es. No hay selector de fecha ni nada en esa entrada de texto. También no hay error. Estoy utilizando **AdminLTE**, **Angular 6** y **Bootstrap4**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El `type=text` debe ser `type= "Date"` si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: Haciendolo de esa manera no carga el DatePicker como en Bootstrap carga el de HTML5 por defecto

Comment: ¿Puedes poner las librerias que estas usando? Bootstrap no tiene un datepicker por defecto. Asumo que estás cargando un plugin del adminlte. Si es así verifica en tus plantillas que este cargando correctamente y copia esa librería.

Comment: Yo he trabajado con componentes DatePicker de bootstrap 3.x y 4.x pero para usar estos componentes utilizo una dependencia se llama ngx-bootstrap el cual te permite utilizar los diferentes componentes de bootstrap en un proyecto Angular. Página oficial: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker ahí podras encontrar la documentación.

Comment: el input tiene que ser de type=Date.